# Unable to filter notebooks on userRole

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I'm trying to get a list of notebooks that I own, my API call is:
`/me/notes/notebooks?filter=userRole eq 'Owner'` (Using the API console, so not replacing spaces here)

The response includes

> 400 (Bad Request) The OData query is invalid. A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Microsoft.OneNote.Api.UserRole' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'Equal'

Without the quotes around the userRole filter we get:

> 400 (Bad Request) Unknown property name: 'Owner'
>   `/me/notes/notebooks?filter=userRole eq Owner`

Is there a correct way to filter on userRole?

**Edit:**

Clutching at straws, but I've also tred

`/me/notes/notebooks?filter=userRole eq Microsoft.OneNote.Api.UserRole.Owner`

Unsuccessfully...

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "20143",
    "message": "The OData query is invalid. The child type 'Microsoft.OneNote.Api.UserRole.Owner' in a cast was not an entity type. Casts can only be performed on entity types.",
    "@api.url": "http://aka.ms/onenote-errors#C20143"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
me/notes/notebooks?$filter=userRole%20eq%20Microsoft.OneNote.Api.UserRole%27Reader%27
```

Works!

Comment: Yes. `userRole eq Microsoft.OneNote.Api.UserRole'Owner'` works via the console. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think white space characters might cause this problem.

Try this;

> filter=userRole%20eq%20'Owner'

Comment: Hi, I am encoding spaces, I'll edit my question, thanks